# Number of bits set in given bitsets at an index

Tags: algorithm, bitset

Given n bitsets , generate a new bitset in which a bit is set at an index , if atleast k out on n bitset has there bit set at that index.

n bitset can vary in size. The size is <= 10<sup>8</sup>

**Example**:

```
n = 3 , k =2
10001
00101
10001
New Bitset : 10001
```

1.**First Approach** :

```
 len = Max size from n bitsets  
 n = number of bitsets 
 n bitsets = List<Bitset> bitsets
 Bitset newBitset = new Bitset(len);
 int count = 0;
 for(int i = 0; i < len; i++){
        count = 0;
        for(Bitset b : bitsets){
            if(b.size() > i && b.get(i)){
                count++;
            }
        }
        if(count >= k){
            newBitset.set(i);
        }
  }
  // Complexity = O(len*n)
```

2. **Second Approach**:
    We can take nCk combinations of bitsets , take AND of each and
    finally take OR of resulting bitsets to get the required bitset.

I am looking for more optimised solution.

Comment: The first approach is optimized enough in terms of time and I think there are no better way to do so. The second is the mother of brute-force.

Comment: You keep going even when you've already found `k` 1's - that can certainly be optimised by breaking out of the loop.